# Using View Binding displays blank white screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I was experimenting View Binding in my new app. Suddenly today when I run the app it displays blank white screen instead of UI. If I remove binding and use setContentView, it works!
Any idea why this is happening?

Code:
build.gradle

```
viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

MainActivity

```
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to call `setContentView` with `ViewBinding` as:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root) // add this
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding!